# Handle display of string or string resource

Tags: android, generics, mvvm, android-livedata, android-architecture

Suppose you apply the following architecture in your Android project:
*View - ViewModel - UseCase - Repository* and you have to display some text from the *UseCase* layer to the *View* layer. However, this text some times is of type `String` and some times is of type `Int` (stringResource).

What is the best practice to handle this?

Comment: which component is providing you with the data String, Int ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try type **Any** and set **case** to decalre type **as String** || **as Int**